# How to use IRepository in Orchard with int key (NOT IDENTITY)

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-mvc, insert, orchardcms, irepository

I'm using Orchard IRepository to manage data and save to db... that's what I'm trying to do.

My class is:

```
public class SocietaRecord
{
    public virtual int Id { get; set; }
    public virtual string Club { get; set; }
    public virtual string Email { get; set; }
}
```

My Migration:

```
SchemaBuilder.CreateTable("SocietaRecord", table => table
    .Column<int>("Id", column => column.PrimaryKey())
    .Column<String>("Club", c => c.Nullable())
    .Column<String>("Email", c => c.Nullable())
);
```

Please note that Id is NOT and IDENTITY

now when I call Repository Create the follow insert is performed:
(grabbed with sql profiler)

```
exec sp_executesql N'INSERT INTO Match_SocietaRecord 
(Club, Email) VALUES (@p0, @p1); 
select SCOPE_IDENTITY()',N'@p0 nvarchar(4000),@p1 nvarchar(4000),
@p0=N'Test',@p1=NULL
```

that fails because it ignores my Id and assumes (incorrectly) that Tables has an autonumber key.

This is the error:

```
NHibernate.Exceptions.GenericADOException: could not insert:
[Match.Models.SocietaRecord]
[SQL: INSERT INTO Match_SocietaRecord (Club, Email) VALUES (?, ?); 
select SCOPE_IDENTITY()] ---> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: 
Cannot insert the value NULL into column 'Id', table ORCHARD.dbo.Match_SocietaRecord'; 
column does not allow nulls. INSERT fails.
```

How explain to repository to look at table and do not assume identity if there is not so that I can insert my own id?
(Yes, I provided a valid Id on object record before creating)

Edit:
I have digged a bit in code and I think that:

- Incorrect Identity is due to Fluent NHibernate: Auto Mapping Conventions
- Orchard overrides incorrect assumpions using IAutoMappingAlteration

so I can change my question in:

How can I define a custom IAutoMappingAlteration for my class to explain Orchard that my Id is not an identity?

or (in other words)

where I can find the "automapping configuration" in orchard as described in Auto-mapping documentation?

https://github.com/jagregory/fluent-nhibernate/wiki/Auto-mapping

(... "You can modify the way the automapper discovers identities by overriding the IsId method in your automapping configuration." ... )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The repository implementation in Orchard is there to be used by higher-level content management API. It is not designed or intended as a general purpose repository implementation or a substitute for an ORM (we have nHibernate under the hoods for that). You should use nHibernate directly. Low-level examples of that in the OrchardPo module: https://bitbucket.org/bleroy/orchardpo/src

Comment: Not sure I understand. Should I not use IRepository for do a simple crud operation on a couple of table just because repository assumes identity where there is not?

Comment: If it's compatible with the conventions and assumptions that were made, why not, but that doesn't seem to be the case here.